# Delta Epsilon proof with weird bounds

Tags: calculus

I have attempted to write a delta epsilon proof proving the limit $$\lim_{x\to \frac{1}{\pi} } \frac{\pi}{x}=\pi^{2}$$

I manipulated the $|f(x)-L|$ part as $$\big| -\frac{\pi^{2}}{x} \big|  \big| x- \frac{1}{\pi} \big|$$

and then let $\delta =1$ and manipulated $\big| x-\frac{1}{\pi}\big|$ which I then used to give me the bounds $$\frac{1-\pi}{\pi} < x < \frac{\pi+1}{\pi} $$  I am not sure if my steps are correct up to this point and am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

We have only to consider values of $x$ near $\frac{1}{\pi}$. Hence we can restrict to $x \ge \frac{1}{2 \pi}$. For those $x$ we get:

$|f(x)-\pi^2|=\frac{\pi^2|\frac{1}{\pi}-x|}{x} \le 2 \pi^3|x-\frac{1}{\pi}|$.

Your turn !